# Google Maps Javascript API V3 - Markers cutted at tile borders

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm developing a geolocation based game. A map with markers is one of the core components of it. We are using

- Phonegap 2.2
- the issue only occurs on Android 4.2.x (tested on Nexus 4, 7 and 10)
- GoogleMaps Api V3
- We are building it with PhonegapBuild
- MarkerImages are used with scaled images (see code below)

Unfortunately I have some problems displaying the markers on the map correctly. It seems that the tiles have a small border around them and that the markers are cut at this borders.
The issue does not occurs always.

After zooming into the map the markers are displayed correctly.

The code below displays how we add our markers and define the map.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom : 14,
            mapTypeControl : false,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(lastPos.lat, lastPos.lon),
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            streetViewControl : false,
            styles : [..]
        });

[some time later, after making sure map is initialized, is displayed and so on...]

var markerimage = {
    url : image,
    size : new google.maps.Size(60, 106),
    origin : new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor : new google.maps.Point(15, 53),
    scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(30, 53)
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : new google.maps.LatLng(spot.position.latitude, spot.position.longitude),
    icon : markerimage,
    optimized : true,
    clickable : true,
    draggable : false,
    map : map,
    zIndex: 2
});
```

Does anyone know something about this issue or how to fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I just tried a few things. I disabled all CSS in the app and all not needed Javascript, I removed custom styles from markers and the map. But the Bug still occurs. Map size is now set to fixed width and height (by pixels). I'm really getting crazy with this bug! The markers duplicate, getting stretched and are cutup...!
I attached a new scrennshot below.

[image: new screenshot]

[image: map with border between tiles and cutted markers].

Comment: Try removing the zIndex: 2,  The maps get renderd in live time and it may be loading in a bad order.  ( IE.  the MArkers are being placed but the map image hasnt actualy loaded till its in view )

Comment: Hmm but then the blue dot isn't over the other markers, like it should. I got if already working by adding a listener to the map. Each time the zoom changes I resize the map. Then all the markers are displayed correctly. But the border between the tiles is still present.

Comment: Is this present when there is no styling on the maps?

Comment: Yes it is. I tested it with no custom styling and only default markers.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to debug because its hard to reproduce - but I am going to try to provide few tips to try out as an answer:

- Markers with images (png, gif) turn `optimized: false` , if this doesnt help try to remove markerImages and see what happens then. Still bugs?
- Remove custom styles from map (try without custom styles and marker images, without custom styles but with marker images etc.)
- Try to listen tilesloaded, bounds_changed etc. events and use debug prints to check whether they are fired. When they do : try to initialize your markers after that - first straight - then with small timeout
- Try to remove scaling of images and special anchor settings etc, try to be as minimal as possible
- Make sure that markerImage(s) are loaded by attaching them to DOM for example. (This is normal and good practice with web images - I dont know if phonegap has something different).

If nothing seems to help - ask from gooooogle :)

Comment: Hej Mauno,thanks for your answer. The first option I already tried. But it seems to exist a memory leak there. If we use it user report crashes of the app on android and ios. The second option is unfortunately no real possibility, because the cooperate identity is one of our key features. But i will have a look at all of them. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yea, just shooting at the dark - to summarize: try to debug it by simplifying as much as possible (basically removing features temporarily from map), then after that (when it works) - start activating that look and feel what it is meant to be used. (step by step) Maybe you can get a trace where it goes wrong. :)

Comment: Hey Mauno, thanks for all your input. Actually I could brake the problem down to something: I removed the custom markers, the custom map style with no success and finally added all the markers after the event tilesloaded. On desktop everything works fine. But when i deploy it to android the tilesloaded event is not fired at all! after adding the listener the map even does not appear anymore. So it seems to be a problem there.

Comment: Ok, no this wasn't the problem. I didn't initialize the gps position listener. Therefore it did not show the map. right now i do only display the markers after tilesloaded event (which is fired) and afterwards I add the markers to the map. but the problem occurs again. I did not understand your last point, attaching the images to the dom. Could you provide an example of it? Do you have any further ideas? Thanks!